# Pagination Of ListView On Scrolling In Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

Can Any one help Me on How to Implement on Handling Pagination on Scrolling of listview in xamarin.android .any link or any sample wil be helpful

Comment: What do you mean pagination on the scrolling?

Comment: i mean first time my list will show only 10 list items,when user scroll it shoud hit api or it should display next 10 items of my listview .

Comment: I have done a similar implementation before will update my code give me a minute

Comment: oh ok...that will be very helpful to me

Comment: I have posted the code take a look, in case of any queries revert.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android pagination is quite easy in comparison to iOS and can be done as follows:

```
 public class EndlessScrollListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Widget.AbsListView.IOnScrollListener
{

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private bool loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener()
    {
    }
    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold)
    {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        if (loading)
        {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal)
            {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
        {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            //new LoadGigsTask().execute(currentPage + 1);
            loading = true;
        }   
    }

    public void OnScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, [GeneratedEnum] ScrollState scrollState)
    {
        //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

Then set it to the listview as follows:

```
List.SetOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
```

**Working of code:**

- visibleThreshold – The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position, before loading more.
- currentPage – The current page of data you have loaded.
- previousTotal – The total number of items in the dataset after the last load.
- loading – True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.

Next, we have a couple of constructors that allow us to set the visibleThreshold inline if we want.

The first overridden method we have is called every time the list is scrolled. This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here. We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data, but first, we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.

If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page number and total item count.

If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data. If we do need to reload some more data, we execute a background task and set the loading flag to true. Thus solving the problem forever!

The last method in the class we do not need, however, if you’re interested, it is primarily used for tracking changes in the scroll action itself via the scrollState parameter.

Finally, the code to call the class creates a new instance of EndlessScrollListener and bind’s it to a ListView of mine. Of course, put your own ListView in place of List.

Comment: only OnScrollStateChanged() is getting called but why OnScroll() is not getting called  @G.hakim

Comment: It gets called when you scroll down and up did you try doing that?

Comment: i did scrolling up and down only OnScrollStateChanged() Is getting called..

Comment: yes i kept breakpoint and checked...its not going to OnScroll()

Comment: Can you post some code so i know what exactly have you done so far

Comment: i have used same EndlessScrollListener class and no change in any piece of code.and i have replaced ur listview with my listview in List.SetOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

Comment: In either case can you update your code please just want to check what is causing the issue!!